# Postgres plsql return one column from table with dynamic type

Tags: postgresql, sql-function, sql-types

I'd like to create function using pgplsql which takes table name and column name and returns this column as result.
The main problem which I faced is dynamic type of this columns (might be int/float/numeric/timestamp/etc)

I created function which returns set of record

```sql
create or replace
function extract_column(
    _table_name text,
    _col_name text)
  returns setof record
  language plpgsql as
$func$
begin
    return QUERY execute format(
        'select %I FROM schema_name.%I',
        _col_name,
        _table_name
    );
end
$func$;
```

And it works if i provide schema while query

```sql
SELECT * FROM extract_column('my_table', 'column812')
    as t(
        data varchar,
    );
```

But I cannot provide this type dynamically from my application, so I prepared another function which returns data type of column by its name

```sql
create or replace
function get_type(table_name text, col_name text)
    returns regtype
language plpgsql as
$func$ 
declare column_type regtype;

begin 
    select
        data_type::regtype
from
        information_schema.columns
where
        table_name = table_name 
    and column_name = col_name
    into
    column_type;

return column_type;
end 
$func$;
```

But I cannot use it in my query

```sql
SELECT * FROM extract_column('my_table', 'column812')
    as t(
        data get_type('my_table', 'column812'),
    );
```

It throws error

```sql
SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "get_type" does not exist
```

What can I do to make this work?

Comment: You won't find a solution with a single query. You'll have to find the type, then construct the SQL statement.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I tried to pass dtype regtype as param of function and put it in `returns` clause or call function get_type in `returns` clause but it also not working.

Comment: No. You have to construct a statement *string*. If you are using PL/pgSQL, you have to execute that statement with `EXECUTE`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, I made function which generate statement and returns it as text. But I cannot execute it in regular sql.
`select generate_sql_statement('my_table', 'column812')` shows the correct sttmnt, but `execute generate_sql_statement('my_table', 'column812')` throws error: _prepared statement "generate_sql_statement" does not exist_

Comment: I was talking about PL/pgSQL, not SQL. I told you that you cannot do it with a single query. Use client code for this.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, thats sad that it connot be done using one or several pl/pgsql functions and select it from standard sql code. Actually client is BI tool which supports only standard sql calls, so I need to call only one pg/plsql function to do that, but of course it may call several functions inside.

Comment: Oh, it works great with a PL/pgSQL function. Construct the SQL string and use `EXECUTE` to run it.